# Remove /product/ from url. I want only category name then product name

Tags: plugins, permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic, slug

I have a site

https://abc/product/accessories/beanie/

But I want this

```
https://abc/accessories/beanie/
```

Mainly I have to remove /product/ (/shop/) from url.

[image]

Using this I got right permalink but my page not working.

I got this message.

"The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Can please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing these isn't advisable, you can refer the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/) but still if you want to do it, you can use [WooCommerce Permalink Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/).